# Using jQuery to time css animation loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want jQuery to toggle a class on so that it triggers a set of CSS animations. I then want that animation to loop once it finishes. So, basically, when the page loads I want the class added (which triggers a set of css animations). Then, once the animations are done after around 6 seconds, I want the class to be removed and immediately added back for another 6 seconds and so on.

I found this code on a different post, which sort of does what I want:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

  setInterval(function() {

    $('.hero_wrapper').addClass('start_anim');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hero_wrapper').removeClass('start_anim');
    }, 6000);

  }, 7000)

});
```

The trouble with this code is that it seems to wait for 7 seconds before initially adding the class. To get around this, and make it add the class as soon as the page has loaded, I've done the following:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

$('.hero_wrapper').addClass('start_anim');//adds the class

setTimeout(function() {//waits 6 seconds to remove the class
  $('.hero_wrapper').removeClass('start_anim');
}, 7000);

  setInterval(function() {

    $('.hero_wrapper').addClass('start_anim');//adds the class

    setTimeout(function() {//waits 6 seconds to remove the class
      $('.hero_wrapper').removeClass('start_anim');
    }, 7000);

  }, 8000)//repeats the process every 8 seconds

});
```

Basically I just added the class to begin with, and a setTimeout to remove it again in time for the setInterval to start for the first time. This feels like a very inelegant solution and I'm sure I'm doing something dumb here. Does anyone have a better, less verbose way to get what I want.

Comment: Use toggle class like this http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D7XsJ/

Comment: QuantumPuter looking at that fiddle it simply toggles between the classes every 1 second. The trouble is that I need to toggle between two classes at different intervals. Ie immediately on for 6 secs, off for 1sec on for 6 secs off for 1 sec and so on.